# Panel reload after Checkbox Click

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, richfaces

I have the following scenario (using rich faces):

```
  ...
  <a4j:outputPanel id="foo">
    <h:commandButton disabled="#{not _user.selected}" value="Do Stuff" />
  </a4j:outputPanel>
  ...
  <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{_user.selected}">
  </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
  ...
```

I now want the 'foo' panel to reload when I click the checkbox. What's the correct way to add the reload functionality to the checkbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since you are using richfaces (as you tagged):

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{_user.selected}">
   <a4j:support event="onclick" reRender="foo" ajaxSingle="true"/>
  </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

Comment: Thanks, i knew it had to be something simple which I just overlooked ;-)